# How to make a GIF with large dimentions?

Tags: windows-7, gif

I have 4 large photos (2448x3264).  I'd like to make them into a GIF of the same size with 4 frames separated 100ms.

I've tried various software off the net (Free Gif Maker and the like), but they all seem to limit the dimensions to relatively small sizes.

How can I make the GIF that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imagemagick is an open source (free) command line utility that allows you to convert images:

[Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

Here's a tutorial on GIFs: [http://www.tjhsst.edu/~dhyatt/supercomp/n401a.html](http://www.tjhsst.edu/%7Edhyatt/supercomp/n401a.html)

The command you're looking for is "convert"

```
convert -delay 20 -loop 0 sphere*.gif animatespheres.gif
```

(`-delay` is in ms, `-loop` is optional)

> This will take all of the source frames and will make them into one animated GIF image
> called animatespheres.gif. The -delay 20 argument will cause a 20 hundredths of a second
> delay between each frame, and the -loop 0 will cause the gif to loop over and over
> again.